# Find the number of non-empty subsets S such that min(S) + max(S) <= K

Tags: java, algorithm

For a given vector of integers and integer `K`, find the number of non-empty subsets `S` such that `min(S) + max(S) <= K`

For example, for `K = 8` and vector `[2, 4, 5, 7]`, the solution is 5: `([2], [4], [2, 4], [2, 4, 5], [2, 5])`.
The time complexity should be O(n^2).

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant to do your homework. Please provide attempts you tried so that people can help pinpoint what exactly you're doing wrong. You might also want to tag a language if necessary.

Comment: This was asked in an interveiw , I generated all subsets and arrived at an exponential solution, lemme know if it can be done better!

Comment: @Mat This isnt abt homewrk! :) I dint know now that stackoverflow is no longer a place to discuss algorithmic qs.

Comment: You would usually want to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. It's easier for people to help you when we know what's been tried.

Comment: @Samarya it still is, but not everyone agrees. I would untag Java because it's bringing this question to the attention of that crowd.

Comment: @SamayraGoyal: regardless whether it is an interview, exam, programming contest, homework, etc. One is supposed to put effort in solving the problem oneself, and *show* that effort in the question. For example if you have an alorithm with a different time complexity, that is some effort, or the analysis you made and the things you've tried (but did not work).

Answer (score 1):

On the algorithmic side: as you already said, there is a (basic) solution where we count all subsets; but iterating over subsets has exponential complexity.

We can optimize counting: consider in example the set `S=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` , we want to count all subsets that contain both `1` and `6`. There are 4 items between 1 and 6; and all subsets we are counting will either contain or not contain any of `[2,3,4,5]`. Since they are 4 items, there are `2^4` different subsets.

So for the solution; you can iterate over the array (complexity `N`) and select the minimum; iterate over the following items and select the maximum (complexity `N` again); and count the number of subsets between `i` and `j` (they are `2^n`).